# Error passing information from servlet to jsp file

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am trying to send data from the InformationServlet servlet to the information.jsp file it redirects to.
The InformationServlet is the following:

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.*;
import java.io.IOException;

@WebServlet(name = "Information", value = "/Information")
public class InformationServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("administration.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        request.setAttribute("myemail",email);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("information.jsp").forward(request, response); // forward the email to the .jsp


    }
}
```

and the information.jsp is:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.SQLException"%>


<%-- Database information --%>
<%
    String id = request.getParameter("userid");
    String driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
    String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    String database = "employees";
    String userid = "root";
    String password = "password";
    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>information</title>
</head>
<body>
<% String member_email =  (String)request.getAttribute("myemail");
    try{

        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl+database, userid, password);
        statement = connection.prepareStatement("Select surname, name, email, phone, CV from member left join resume on memberEmail = email where email = ?");
        statement.setString(1, member_email);
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
        resultSet.next();

%>
<div id="table">
    <a action="Information" method="post" class="table-row">
        <span class="table-cell" name="surname"> <%=resultSet.getString("surname") %> </span>
        <span class="table-cell" name="firstname"> <%=resultSet.getString("name") %> </span>
        <span class="table-cell" name="email"> <%=resultSet.getString("email") %> </span>
        <span class="table-cell" name="phone"> <%=resultSet.getString("phone") %> </span>
        <span class="table-cell" name="cv"> <%=resultSet.getString("cv") %> </span>
</div>
<%

        connection.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically the .jsp file retrieves some information from the database "employees" depending on the "myemail" parameter passed from the servlet. I've searched it up a lot online and from what I found this is the correct way of establishing a communication between the two file types, yet the member_email variable in the scriplet of the "information.jsp" file is null somehow. This is my first attempt of building a web application, so the usage of servlets/jsps is rather new to me, so maybe I have an obvious mistake.
Also in case it is needed, the "administration.jsp" the "InformationServlet" listens from is the following:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>

<%-- Database information --%>
<%
    String id = request.getParameter("userid");
    String driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
    String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    String database = "employees";
    String userid = "root";
    String password = "password";
    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Administration Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css_files/initial.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Administration Page</h1>

<%
    try{
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl+database, userid, password);
        statement=connection.createStatement();
        String sql ="select surname, name, email from member";
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);

        //each row will be filled with looping throw the table in the database
        while(resultSet.next()){
%>
    <div id="table">
        <form method="post" action="information.jsp" class="table-row">
            <span class="table-cell" name="surname"> <%=resultSet.getString("surname") %> </span>
            <span class="table-cell" name="firstname"> <%=resultSet.getString("name") %> </span>
            <span class="table-cell" name="email"> <%=resultSet.getString("email") %> </span>
            <button type="submit">Navigate to user information</button>
        </form>
    </div>
<%
        }
        connection.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
%>

</body>
</html>
```

which is working as intended.

Comment: @mnesarco Quite helpful the ironic comment you wrote. Moving aside from it, if the way I am trying to solve my problem isn't correct what should I change in my code, because I definitely need to use SQL to get the data I want. Can I use SQL with JSTL, bcs the https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info says that's it's discouraged to do so.

Comment: JSP, JSTL are super legacy technology, you should avoid it. SQL inside JSP is a bad practice anyway, you should never do that.

Comment: You told me twice what to not do. What SHOULD I do?

Comment: If you want to use java web technologies, use the latest version: JakartaEE 8/9. And use modern web frameworks like React/Angular/Svelt/VUE/... things like that. And All business logic inside logic components, and bridge the two using REST APIs via JaxRS.

Comment: https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jakartaee-tutorial/#the-web-tier

Comment: This is a project for university tho, so I was told to use servlets/jsps etc, also I'm using the intelij Idea IDE.

Comment: Well, jokes apart, teaching JSP in 2021 is a very bad thing and it is a waste of your time.